# Update multiple elements of a Clojure atom

Tags: clojure

I have a atom:

```
(def data (atom[ {:orderid 0 :productid 0 :description "A" :amount 2}  {:orderid 1 :productid 1 :description "A" :amount 2}]))
```

and my swap function:

```
 (defn edit-order [params]
  (filter
        #(and (= (:orderid %) (:orderid params)))
        @data
  (swap! data (fn [old new] (merge old new)) params))
```

The result I got is:

```
(println (edit-order  {:orderid 0 :description "edited" :amount 3})) 
;=> [{:orderid 0, :productid 0, :description A, :amount 2} {:orderid 1, :productid 1, :description A, :amount 2} {:orderid 0, :description edited, :amount 3}]
```

What I trying to do is update the new value to old value not just add it as a new one. How should I do that?

```
;=> [{:orderid 0, :productid 0, :description edited, :amount 3} {:orderid 1, :productid 1, :description A, :amount 2}]
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go about this is:

```
(def data (atom
           [{:orderid 0 :productid 0 :description "A" :amount 2}
            {:orderid 1 :productid 1 :description "A" :amount 2}]))

(defn edit-order
  [params]
  (swap! data
         (fn [old-orders]
           (mapv (fn [order]
                   (if (= (:orderid order)
                          (:orderid params))
                     (merge order params)
                     order))
                 old-orders))))

(comment
  (edit-order {:orderid 0 :description "edited" :amount 3})
  #_ [{:orderid 0, :productid 0, :description "edited", :amount 3}
      {:orderid 1, :productid 1, :description "A", :amount 2}]
  )
```

Notice that you cannot mutate just one map inside a vector. You are creating an entirely new vector based on the old one, because the entire data structure inside the atom is (should be) immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you're doing a lot of nested structure manipulation, is to use https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter, in this case the "transform" operation.

```
(ns specterplay.core
  (:require [com.rpl.specter :refer :all]))

(def data (atom[ {:orderid 0 :productid 0 :description "A" :amount 2}  {:orderid 1 :productid 1 :description "A" :amount 2}]))

(defn edit-order!
  [params data]
  (swap! data
         (fn [a] (transform [ALL #(= (:orderid params) (:orderid %))] #(merge % params) a))))

(edit-order! {:description "edited" :amount 3} data)

@data
;; [{:orderid 0, :productid 0, :description "edited", :amount 3} {:orderid 1, :productid 1, :description "A", :amount 2}]
```

Comment: What does the 0 in #(= 0 (:orderid %)) mean?

Comment: Oops, should be (:orderid params). Fixed.